# Laravel not sending email on my server but sends on localhost

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel is not send email on my server but sending on localhost. Below is my code

```
Mail::to($email)->send(new SendConfirmation($firstname, $phone));

<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class sendConfirmation extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    private $userFirstname;
    private $userKey;

    public function __construct($userFirstname, $userKey)
    {
        $this->userFirstname = $userFirstname;
        $this->userKey = $userKey;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from("kenny@gmail.com",'XYZ')
        ->subject("Registration Successful")
        ->with('userFirstname', $this->userFirstname)
        ->with('userKey', $this->userKey)
        ->view('email.confirm-account');
    }
}

view
<div>
Dear {{ $userFirstname }}, Thanks for signing up. Please click the 
link below to verify your account.
</div>
```

**Expected output**

*Dear John, Thanks for signing up. Please click the link below to verify your account.*

Comment: Hello, can you give us you config/mail.php file?

Comment: Is your configuration the same on both servers?

Comment: Your MAIL_HOST in your env. file is most probably still set on localhost

Comment: Are you using Gmail smtp? I had a lot of trouble making it work in various projects, it was working on local but not on production. Now I create an email on my server (noreply@domainname.extension) and everything works way better

Comment: My config/mail.php

Comment: Yes I'm using Gmail smtp

Comment: My configuration is the same on both servers

Comment: Are you using an VPS or a Shared Hosting service?

Comment: I'm using shared hosting service

Answer (score 0):

*My config/mail.php*

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
|            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Markdown Mail Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
| theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
| of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
|
*/

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Log Channel
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using the "log" driver, you may specify the logging channel
| if you prefer to keep mail messages separate from other log entries
| for simpler reading. Otherwise, the default channel will be used.
|
*/

'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
```

];